# Access a Java Class with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I created a java file and compiled it. Now I have the directory WEB-INF/classes with HelloWorld.java and HelloWorld.class

Now the question is: How do I access it via Tomcat? It is installed, the examples Tomcat coems with work. I don't know how to access the webdir(the name of the app I created in webapps)

I get the following error:

type Status report

message /webdir/

description The requested resource (/webdir) is not available.

Comment: start with a servlet tutorial

Comment: What is the structure of your webapp?  Do you have a web.xml file, and do you have any servlet mapping to this servlet defined in a web.xml file for your webapp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any program must have an entry point. In the case of normal Java apps, it is a `public static void main(String[] args)`. In the case of a Java web application, the entry points is typically the method `doGet` of the the class [`HttpServlet`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html).

So you must implement a class that extends this `HttpServlet` class. Then, you need to setup a file `webdit/WEB-INF/web.xml` where you will declare your Servlet, and make it visible through a given URL.

Check the examples that come with Tomcat, then google "Servlet", "web.xml" for more details. Good luck.